# This algorithm's complexity is correct?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

The algorithm I do not understand is :

```
alg(m, n)
1. if m>n then
2.     return alg(m-n, n)
3. else
4.     if n>m then
5.          return alg(n, m)
6.     else
7.          return n
```

I think that the recurrence formula is `T(m) = T(m-n) + a`, where a is a constant. I tried to do a substitution:

```
T(m) = T(m-k) + a*n
```

Assume that

`k=m => T(m) = T(0) + a*n => T(m) = n*a + 1 => The complexity is O(n)`.

*Please tell me if I am wrong. Thank you!*

Comment: This algorithm computes the greatest divisor of two integers. For example, if i consider m = 120 and n = 75, the algorithm returns 15. m is the first integer and n is the second integer.

Comment: If m = -1, n = 1 then the recursion never finishes. I guess your numbers are positive integers, right?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that

Answer (score 0):

I searched on the Internet and the complexity of this algorithm is O(n+m). I am posting this to help other people. The link is: https://codility.com/media/train/10-Gcd.pdf